# Is there any "Background Removal" Program in Ubuntu besides GIMP?

Tags: gimp, desktop-background, photoshop, image-processing, image-editor

I need to remove background from images locally. I use photoshop in windows and GIMP in Linux but GIMP is too much for me for simple background removal purpose. Is there any easier alternatives for it.

To be exact, I need this([Background Removal](http://editphotosforfree.com/photoapps/remove-background-from-image-online/)) which is online version but I want to know such program exist in Ubuntu offline version.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install backgroundremover
```

Then simply

```
backgroundremover -i "/path/to/file.jpg" -o "out.png"
```

and if you want for video

```
backgroundremover -i "/path/to/video.mp4" -tg -o "output.gif"
```

source: https://github.com/nadermx/backgroundremover

Answer (score 0):

This function exists in Gimp. This tutorial explain how it works :
https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tutorial-quickie-separate.html

Comment: he specifically ask for a program OTHER than GIMP... please edit your answer or remove it to answer what the op asks! Cheers.